# Group policy central store replication

Tags: group-policy, replication, windows

Should i care about replication traffic, generated by group policy templates central store? Do templates, stored there, replicate with client machines?

Comment: the answer is it depends, how many sites do you have? Is there a wan involved etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The templates stored in the SYSVOL (both old-style ADM templates and new-style ADMX templates) are not replicated to client computers. What you're probably thinking of, when you're thinking of client computers, is the behavior of editing a GPO with updated ADM files on a client computer. Quoting http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929841:

> In Group Policy for versions of Windows earlier than Windows Vista, if
>   you change Administrative template policy settings on local computers,
>   the Sysvol share on a domain controller within your domain is
>   automatically updated with the new .ADM files. ... In
>   Group Policy for Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista, if you change
>   Administrative template policy settings on local computers, Sysvol
>   will not be automatically updated with the new .ADMX or .ADML files.